# error on IBM Blockchain

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger

When I import and run my smart contract on the IBM Blockchain, it looks normal and runs successfully. However, I see the following error again and again:

> [31m07:51:14.774 [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 2d8f [0m Error
>   building images: The command '/bin/sh -c go install
>   github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/f607ca3e-4259-4c1b-bba9-a4361f08acd7
>   && cp src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/core.yaml $GOPATH/bin &&
>   mv $GOPATH/bin/f607ca3e-4259-4c1b-bba9-a4361f08acd7
>   $GOPATH/bin/d9694398ca6ada1e74ef40cbea15348c60626156b89f3c4b2e621f8c6625c65b4d9fda8fc63bdc208a4db1595d7ca2d4b8b4601ac5eeb1f0db35a8551a94403a'
>   returned a non-zero code: 2
>
> [31m07:50:40.956 [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 2d86 [0m Error
>   building images: The command '/bin/sh -c go install
>   github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/f607ca3e-4259-4c1b-bba9-a4361f08acd7
>   && cp src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/core.yaml $GOPATH/bin &&
>   mv $GOPATH/bin/f607ca3e-4259-4c1b-bba9-a4361f08acd7
>   $GOPATH/bin/d9694398ca6ada1e74ef40cbea15348c60626156b89f3c4b2e621f8c6625c65b4d9fda8fc63bdc208a4db1595d7ca2d4b8b4601ac5eeb1f0db35a8551a94403a'
>   returned a non-zero code: 2
>
> [31m07:50:34.481 [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 2d84 [0m Error
>   building images: The command '/bin/sh -c go install
>   github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/f607ca3e-4259-4c1b-bba9-a4361f08acd7
>   && cp src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/core.yaml $GOPATH/bin &&
>   mv $GOPATH/bin/f607ca3e-4259-4c1b-bba9-a4361f08acd7
>   $GOPATH/bin/d9694398ca6ada1e74ef40cbea15348c60626156b89f3c4b2e621f8c6625c65b4d9fda8fc63bdc208a4db1595d7ca2d4b8b4601ac5eeb1f0db35a8551a94403a'
>   returned a non-zero code: 2
>
> [31m07:45:46.971 [rest] processChaincodeInvokeOrQuery -> ERRO 2d4d [0m
>   Error when querying chaincode: Error:Failed to launch chaincode
>   spec(Error starting container: The command '/bin/sh -c go install
>   github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/6cd0d810-a766-43c0-b183-aa9c3e063d03
>   && cp src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/core.yaml $GOPATH/bin &&
>   mv $GOPATH/bin/6cd0d810-a766-43c0-b183-aa9c3e063d03
>   $GOPATH/bin/62730368d5c320db93a8bf3bc07f0b3a861d86e0983bbb37d081ada2fc5118b51bc19c16e08bac6b7d4a6438cc9d022c7b8c0763f4166546c697f470ffda7952'
>   returned a non-zero code: 2)
>
> [31m07:45:46.971 [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 2d4c [0m Error
>   building images: The command '/bin/sh -c go install
>   github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/6cd0d810-a766-43c0-b183-aa9c3e063d03
>   && cp src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/core.yaml $GOPATH/bin &&
>   mv $GOPATH/bin/6cd0d810-a766-43c0-b183-aa9c3e063d03
>   $GOPATH/bin/62730368d5c320db93a8bf3bc07f0b3a861d86e0983bbb37d081ada2fc5118b51bc19c16e08bac6b7d4a6438cc9d022c7b8c0763f4166546c697f470ffda7952'
>   returned a non-zero code: 2

Anyone know what happens? Thank you.

Comment: Is this a programming question or a more support type of question? If the latter, perhaps this question would be better suited on [SU]?

Comment: Hi, I don't think it's a programming question because when I deploy the example smart contract. There are also errors, not not the same.

Comment: I think Super User is for hard ware, isn't it? And there isn't my tag, blockchain. @LasseV.Karlsen

Answer (score 0):

This basically says the chaincode did not build for some reason. Wish we had a way to get the actual failure but there's no easy way to get such errors from docker build (AFAIK anyway).

Couple of things to check. (1) does it build in your local env (say when running peer in --peer-chaincodedev mode) and (2) A typical failure would be due to an import that's not in the fabric. It might build in your local env where the import might be available somehow but would fail in the docker env.

Comment: Hi, I never try my code in my local environment. But these days, I am trying to debug my code in my local environment. I'll see. And thank you.